# Using ARKit or SceneKit, how would I contour the scene geometry with a custom image?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, mesh, lidar

I stumbled upon this github repo that colours the surface geometry differently from normal using the "renderer" method on ARSCNViewDelegate: https://github.com/evstinik/arkit3.5-scenereconstruction-visualization
I'm wondering if there's a way of selectively putting an image that I want on the surface geometry, leaving the rest unaltered?

I am making an AR app that projects a 2D image onto surface geometry using raycasts. It works pretty well to project an image onto a given surface. However, if the raycasts are happening only from one direction, sometimes the contouring doesn't work all that well. Furthermore, if I translate or scale or rotate the image, the contouring stays the same as how it was before.

EDIT: btw, not looking for THE solution, just looking for anything that could point me in the right direction. For example, is there a way of getting the texture position using real world coordinates and colouring that?